# Why does my ubuntu 14.10 have an issue when logging out?

Tags: 14.10

I have an issue when I try to log out, it takes a while to "load" out of desktop. I have cinnamon, GNOME  (both metacity, and compiz), KDE,  and unity 7.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Can you post your system specs, kernel version, architecture, and a more throrough description of the problem?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10, 3.16.0 for kernel version. ASUS X550LA, intel core i7. Haven't had any issues until late...

Comment: Ok can you try logging out, recreating the issue, and than post some `dmesg` logs here?

Comment: Also a list of what programs are running when this happens, like the output of `ps aux` may be useful.

Comment: Uninstalled and purged cinnamon desktop that seems to have fixed the issue....

Comment: It seemed to work but only for unity...

Comment: Hmm well I would not install too many desktop environments. They come with so many variations of programs that do the same thing, and it can make systems a bit messy. Also, what seemed to work on Unity...?

Comment: Yes it logs out fine I will log out again to see if iwt was just a fluke.... it was taking forever now... I think it might have something to do with the update notifier popping  up just before I get a chance to log out...

Comment: Removing KDE to see if it works... actually going to remove all desktops but steam login and unity 7

Comment: Great, glad you are making progress. So it's looking like you had too many desktop environments and they were conflicting with each other. Let me know if that was indeed the problem and I will write all this into an answer.

Comment: Purging KDE at this time and removing related libraries.

Comment: Did not work still slow to log out after purge of KDE and its libraries. it should be faster right?

Comment: Ok so I only have both types of gnome... metacity and compiz... how should I handle those?

Comment: I think you should post a dmesg log so that I can see what is going on that is causing your problem, or we should move this to a chat for now. It's up to you how many/which environments you have.  It's looking like something else is causing your problem. Please post `dmesg` output.

Comment: Well it is working now have no idea why... but it is just too many desktops I think...

Comment: Ok, yeah could definitely do it.  Would you like me to write this into an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: Yes sir I would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In certain cases, installing multiple desktop environments on a system may cause instability. This is likely because each comes with a variety of packages that do similar things, and thus will be competing for resources, and/or conflicting with each other. Since your problem resolved after removing some of those desktop environments, it's likely that was what causing your problem.